# What is the current state of US's dilemma on waiving CAATSA for India?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, congress, india, sanctions

India's purchase of Russian S-400 was eligible for [CAATSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countering_America%27s_Adversaries_Through_Sanctions_Act) sactions.

No sanctions have been applied yet using CAATSA. 
There were talks that India would get a waiver, and
there was [a house of representatives vote](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/us-house-votes-for-india-specific-caatsa-waiver/article65642679.ece) approving this sometime back.

I haven't found anything after that vote.

What is the status of this waiver? Why is it not progressing?